# Tenure track and date of publishing

Tags: soft-question

My question is with regards to date of publications and the tenure track process.

I will be starting a tenure track position this fall and I recently submitted a few papers for publication and I used the address of my new institution on the papers.

For my position I get re-examined at the end of year 2 and they decide whether to keep me on and let me continue on with the tenure track process.

I have heard, in general, that one is examined for what one does while at the institution and not what one did before arriving.    My question is, if this is the case,  how would one decide the cut-off date.    Would it be by submission date, publication date or acceptance date of papers or would they just look at the address I used on the papers?

I realize this might very much depend on the particular school.

thanks

Comment: I do not see a good reason why you cannot simply ask somebody at this/your institution. Vote to close. 

Comment: There is no point worrying about this much. The reappointment process after 2 years is usually based on both work before arriving as well as after, since how much you can do after you  arrive is rather limited.

The papers will become a substantial issue in your tenure case, only if your productivity while at the institution is marginal. So try to make sure it isn't.

Comment: Maybe I've just been on the wrong committees, but I have not seen questions like this decided along such strict datelines. From what I hear this freewheeling approach may be a US thing, and they may be more picky about exact rules in Europe.

Comment: I could  tell you the policy at my institution, but different places can have different rules. You really *should* talk to your department Chair or some other senior person and clarify all of these issues. I'm voting to close.

Comment: You should ask this at http://academia.stackexchange.com/